# Using schottky diode near reverse breakdown region

Tags: diodes, converter, flyback, schottky

I am currently using a 1N7070 schottky diode as the output rectifier for a flyback converter. The designed reverse blocking voltage is 70V. However, due to leakage elements I am seeing a transient spike(upto 98V) in the voltage when the primary MOSFET turns ON. This is after I had used a secondary RC snubber element over the diode.

I face two issues now.

1) How would one go about reducing this spike (other than using a proper RC snubber)

2) Does operating the diode with these characteristics result in failure
(A Microsemi note says that the breakdown voltage of these diodes is typically 20-30% above the rated value (and that too with some guard ring?))

Edit: Rated reverse voltage  = 100V

Comment: As long as the current is limited, going into reverse breakdown generally won't damage anything. According to the [datasheet](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/16cyq100c.pdf), the *working* (repetitive) peak reverse voltage is 100V.

Comment: How much current will this diode be passing? Is a standard Si diode out of the question?

Comment: There isn't a lot of current. The estimated current through the diode is a peak value of 2A and an average of 0.4A. Though changing the diode is a great option, II am stuck with this diode for now

Comment: Then it should be fine. However, note that the 1N7070 is a very high-power device, which may have several consequences: (1) the forward voltage will be relatively high in comparison to other Schottky (or even Si) diodes, and (2) it will have a high reverse leakage current.